# Regular expression to extract number, whitespace & fraction from a string

Tags: regex

I have difficulty reading & writing regex's and I want to extract the number, whitespace and fraction from the following string:

**Given String:** `01/10/2017 5 1/2 Liverpool`

**Expected Result:** `5 1/2`.

What regex should I use?

Comment: Language of preference?

Comment: The regex you need is rather simple. Have you tried anything that did not work for you?

Comment: Please indicate what types of strings are you dealing with, or is it just the one string in the question ?

Comment: The example string is just an example, in this case, I just want to find the match '5 1/2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
\b\d+\s+\d+\/\d+\b
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdUAii/1)

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - a [Word-boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `\d+` - matches 1+ digits
- `\s+` - matches 1+ spaces
- `\d+\/\d+` - matches 1+ digits followed by a `/` followed by 1+ digits
- `\b` - Word-boundary